# the html crawled is different from the one in browser

Tags: web-crawler

I use web harvest to get HTMLs, but I find that the one I've got is slightly different from the one in my browser. A couple of numbers in the html are replaced with a dash (`-`) in the HTML crawled with web harvest.

All other content of the HTMLs are the same. Even if I replaced the http statement of web harvest with Java code to request the HTML, that still didn't work.

I guarantee the URLs in my browser and in http request in web harvest are identical. How can I make this work?

Comment: It is quite obvious you dont know much about how webharvest actually handles http requests.  Please read up on "post and get requests" and on "UserAgent". Many websites will display diferently in a recent version of Chrome,  in an ancient InternetExplorer 6 or on a mobile device (the html returned is different)

Comment: Always post code snippets,  and say what you tried so far,  specify the program you are using.  Please read:http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

This problem is very common, often there is a problem with CSS related content. The main reasons are
1. The elements is different from the web source code, which is the most common phenomenon. The code of the elements has been rendered by JS. It's normal that it's different. You can check the elements and source code of Google's homepage, which is obviously different as shown below.[Elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bj5jC.png)[View-Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXezW.png) This should take the web page source code as the standard.
2. Asynchronous problem.
3. If the source code of the web page is different from that of the crawler, it may be due to anti crawling